# 2 different values for the same key

Tags: sql, hiveql

My table:

```
booking_id
arrivel_time
departure_time
date
```

I have cases that for the same key (booking_id) I have 2 records - the first one is with null on arrivel_time and departure_time and the second is with values (date and time) on the arrivel_time and departure_time or only in arrival time.

I would like to select only the record that the booking_id is with the values if it happens.

I am struggling with how to select that, would you be able to explain how to achieve this?

You can see an example of my desired results [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlTd1.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Can it happen that you have a single line with null values that you want  in the output?

Comment: @ Karlheim Yes.

Comment: Please see the example as asked https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlTd1.png

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by booking_id order by arrival_time nulls last) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

In older versions of Hive, you can use:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by booking_id 
                                order by (case when arrival_time is not null then 1 else 2 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! in case there is for one key only null values, is this record will be selected?

Comment: Hey, I have got an error which says (Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:78 missing ) at 'null' near 'arrival_time' in selection target
)while running it

Comment: @Matias021 . . . `nulls last` is a relatively recent addition to Hive.  I added an alternative for earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX()` and `DISTINCT` functions to get the desired result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
booking_id
MAX(arrivel_time),
MAX(departure_time),
date
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY booking_id, date
```

However in this case, what the `MAX()` function does is that it gets the latest date when the booking was updated, so in the event that you have for example one record having `04/05/2021 08:00` as your arrival time and another record with the same booking id having `04/05/2021 09:00` as your arrival time; then it will ignore the first and take the second.

The query I gave you above only works if one of the booking ids has a null value or if both are null.

The `DISTINCT` function is then used to consolidate 2 rows having the **EXACT SAME VALUES** into 1 row.